# JDBC Certificate Requirements for connection in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: java, ssl, google-apps-script, jdbc, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to connect to an on-premises sql server (Microsoft Sql Server Express), but I keep getting an error that has to do with the validation of the certificate.

Connections through locally-run java (with JDBC) work when I pass `encrypt=false` or `trustServerCertificate=true`, otherwise I get an error message :

> "Error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

I know that Google Apps Scripts allows for using self-signed certificates [(as documented here)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getconnectionurl,-info), but I'm not sure what they're actually looking for in the `_serverSslCertificate`, `_clientSslCertificate`, or `_clientSslKey` fields.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to share more details about the network I'm working in. I've tried applying self-signed certificates generated with PowerShell and Windows IIS to the server, but it simply doesn't restart after I do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These parameters require SSL certificates and key of the server and client. As documented [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761592#comment18), you can see the expected values they need on those parameters. See snippet below:

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://<ip address>/<db name>?useSSL=true', { 
  user: '<user>', 
  password: '<pass>', 
  _serverSslCertificate: '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n...\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----', 
  _clientSslCertificate: '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n...\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----', 
  _clientSslKey: '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----' 
});
```

You can try the above snippet but this is for MySQL originally and is reported to have not worked for Microsoft SQL Server. The latter has its own issue posted [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72051695) but still doesn't have any updates.

Guides that might help you are linked below.

#### References:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc
- https://trang-nguyen-ngoc.medium.com/import-data-from-ms-sql-server-to-google-sheets-using-google-apps-script-d92098ea16ee (establish sql connection)